# How to Concatenate Row1 + Row2 with email extension? TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python

I am new and have looked on this forum and online but cannot find a specific solution to my problem. Sorry if this seems easy for you guys!

I have a .csv file that I want to eventually import. There are three columns: First_Name, Last_Name, and Email_Extension.

Desired output format:First_Name.Last_Name@Email_Extension

This is my code so far:

```
First_Name =['Name1', 'Name2']
Last_Name = ['Last1', 'Last2']

Emails = First_Name + Last_Name

Final = Emails + '@gmail.com'

print(Final)
```

Output should be: Name1.Last1@Gmail.com & Name2.Last2@Gmail.com

Thanks so much for your help! Also, any general tips and guidance/resource for data architecture is much appreciated!

Comment: You'll want to look into [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: `zip`. Try this: `[f'{f}.{l}@gmail.com' for f, l in zip(First_Name, Last_Name)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`zip`** and **`join`**:

```
First_Name =['Name1', 'Name2']
Last_Name = ['Last1', 'Last2']

print('\n'.join(f'{x}.{y}@gmail.com' for x, y in zip(First_Name, Last_Name)))

# Name1.Last1@gmail.com
# Name2.Last2@gmail.com
```

Problem with your code is you are trying to concatenate *str* to a *list*. You could only concatenate *list* to a *list*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip()` to merge your two lists:

```
first_name_list =['Name1', 'Name2']
last_name_list = ['Last1', 'Last2']

final_email_list = []
for first_name, last_name in zip(first_name_list, last_name_list):
    email = first_name + "." + last_name + "@gmail.com"
    final_email_list.append(email)

print(final_email_list[0]) # outputs: Name1.Last1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `zip` and then use the string `join` function:

```
First_Name =['Name1', 'Name2']
Last_Name = ['Last1', 'Last2']
print(' & '.join([x+'.'+y+'@gmail.com' for x,y in list(zip(First_Name,Last_Name))]))
```

Output:

```
Name1.Last1@gmail.com & Name2.Last2@gmail.com
```

Or if you want a list, Try this:

```
First_Name =['Name1', 'Name2']
Last_Name = ['Last1', 'Last2']
print([x+'.'+y+'@gmail.com' for x,y in list(zip(First_Name,Last_Name))])
```

Output:

```
['Name1.Last1@gmail.com', 'Name2.Last2@gmail.com']
```

You can do a lot of stuff with lists, here is the documentation of it: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)